# reg expression - replace text with new line for all occurances - php

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I am trying to replace "XYZ" with "\n" newline using regex. but i am not succeeded. Please check the below code and help me out.

```
$epText = "this is for text |XYZ and |XYZ and XYZ";
$find = '|XYZ';
$replace = '\n';
$epFormatedText = preg_replace_callback(
    '/{{.+?}}/',
    function($match) use ($find, $replace) {
        return str_replace($find, $replace, $match[0]);
    },
    $epText
  );
 echo $epFormatedText;
```

But it is show original text. no action is performed. Please help on this.

Comment: `preg_replace('~\bXYZ\b~', '\n', $stre)`

Comment: Your `{{.+?}}` regex matches 2 `{`s then at least 1 character that is not a newline, and then 2 `}`s. Your input does not fit this.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you use single quotes around `\n` in `$replace`. That way, `\n` is treated as a literal `\` + `n` characters.

As for regex, I suggest using `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` look-arounds since you are looking to match whole words, not parts of other longer words (judging by your example).

As the input (`$find`) can contain special regex metacharacters you need to use `preg_quote` to escape those symbols.

Here is your fixed code:

```
$epText = "this is for text |XYZ and |XYZ and XYZ";
$find = '|XYZ';
$replace = "\n";
$epFormatedText = preg_replace(
    "/(?<!\\w)" . preg_quote($find) . "(?!\\w)/",
    $replace,
    $epText
  );
 echo $epFormatedText;
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/o5Hqj9)

Comment: Please note the use of `preg_replace` here, it is simpler than `preg_replace_callback` and is more appropriate here. Also, when declaring a regex with double quotes, regex metacharacters (like `\b`) must be double-escaped.

Comment: stribizhev,  Thanks for quick response. I changed my Question (Added PIP(|) symbol). For that its not working. For my previous one, your answer is working perfectly.

Comment: Please see my update. Still, `preg_replace` solution is the most viable here I think.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it in a wrong way you only need `preg_replace` over simply like as

```
$epText = "this is for text |XYZ and |XYZ and XYZ";
$find = '|XYZ';
$replace = '\n';

echo preg_replace("/\B" . preg_quote($find) . "\b/","\n",$epText);
```

Note : Take care of using quotes over here.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/442176)

Comment: Its working fine for my example. But one more issue is I am trying to replace "|XYZ", but its not working properly. can you please advise me how can i work with PIPE symbol

Comment: Can you post an input string along with expected output

Comment: $epText = "this is for text |XYZ and |XYZ and XYZ";

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for such a complicated function when `preg_replace` should do what you need.

```
$epText = "this is for text XYZ and XYZ and XYZ";
$replaced = preg_replace('@XYZ@',"\n",$epText);

echo '<textarea>', $replaced ,'</textarea>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo  preg_replace('/XYZ/', '<br>', $epText);
```